# Internet Explorer, Flash POST variables and IFRAMES

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, post, iframe, cross-domain

I've had a customer who was getting some weird issues happening with a flash object embedded in an iframe, which called a PHP script and passed POST variables.

I think I've finally figured out roughly what is going on, but would appreciate clarification as to whether or not my hunch is right.

The setup is kind of complicated so please bear with me...

Her web site uses one of those site-builder setups, so it's a bit limited in what it can do.  She wanted to include my Flash application, but couldn't, so as a workaround she put the Flash app on another domain, and then embedded it with an iframe.

Part of what the Flash app does is to open a separate window, and then call a PHP script, passing POST variables to it.

On Chrome, Safari, and Firefox it works. On IE, it's as if no POST variables were posted.

With an HTTP sniffer I was able to confirm that the variables were indeed sent, but the result clearly shows that the PHP script does not see them.

This was really driving me nuts, until I remembered that there are two DIFFERENT domains here.

Remember how she had to embed the content from one domain in an iframe in a different domain?

So I'm thinking it's a cross-domain security issue that is causing the POST data to be blocked server-side.

But then why does it work in other browsers?

Here's my theory...

In Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, the browser sends the data to the script with the page INSIDE the IFrame as the originator.  Therefore the originator and the destination script are on the SAME domain.

In IE, the browser sends the data to the script with the CONTAINER page as the originator. In this case the originator and the destination script are on DIFFERENT domains, and the server blocks the data.

So, what do you think? Does that sound like a valid explanation? Is this a known feature of IE? What should a standards-compliant browser do in this situation?

UPDATE:

It turns out that the problem is NOT just for cross-domain. Even with the iframe content coming from the SAME site it still happens. Only in IE though.  Weird right?

Answer (score 0):

I've worked around Flash cross-domain issues in the past but haven't run into this particular scenario. I don't suppose her site builder would allow deploying a cross-domain policy file to the root of her site?

If so you could try deploying a crossdomain.xml:

```
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*.flashfiledomain.com" secure="false"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

...to the root of her site and see if that resolves the issue. I'm assuming the Flash file and PHP script are both on the same domain?